# WebBrowser control uses too much CPU and RAM

Tags: vb.net, timer, browser

In my application I have only a webbrowser and a few timers, but if the webbrowser is loading, it uses 50% of the CPU and afer 5 minutes around of 120k RAM. What can I do?

My code:

```
Public Sub work()
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("Site")
    tim.Start()
End Sub

Public Sub work2()
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementFromPoint(point).InvokeMember("click")
    tim2.Start()
    tim.Stop()
End Sub

Dim point As New Point(800, 30)
Dim WithEvents tim As New Timer
Dim WithEvents tim2 As New Timer

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    tim.Interval = 6000
    tim2.Interval = 6000
    work()
End Sub

Private Sub tim_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tim.Tick
    work2()
End Sub

Private Sub tim2_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tim2.Tick
    work()
End Sub
```

Comment: Surely it is 120 *megabytes*?

Answer (score 1):

Long, Time ago since this was asked, but as i write this i have been working on my own project to create a YouTube app from Vb.net and, for a few weeks i have been stuck on trying to figure out why the IE Wrapper Web Control was taking so much of my CPU when Processing and Playing Videos, and from a lack of finding any good help with my problem that solved anything, i eventually researched enough and found a solution to my problem which were the use of Feature Registry Entries that i added for my program to check and add as needed on startup of the program, and the two i found which were a lot of help were both FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION and FEATURE_GPU_RENDERING, By Default i believe and could be wrong, the vb.net wrapper uses IE7 but if you change it to the latest version for your program in there it will make it more secure and improve performance, than you can turn on the gpu rendering with a DWORD subkey of 1 with the name of your program and it will make the gpu handle some of the workload also greatly improving the speed. using these made the webcontrol go from utilizing around 70-80% CPU during videos down to low of 3% and high of 20% CPU utilization, good for future reference, also learn more about the registry features here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330733(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

120k sounds very reasonable if there is some heavy web page loaded in the control. E.g. if you save the main page of microsoft.com from within IE in a mht format (complete archive), it is almost 1MB large. The processor usage will most probably depend on what the click handler does - is there any heavy script attached to the element?

Comment: Yes...It is, but what can I do to reduce the CPU and RAM consumption? Because after 2-3 hours the program stops to respond and closes.

Comment: If there aren't any references to web page elements held by your application, nor event handlers added, it might be a problem in the browser control itself. Maybe you could replace the control instance with a new one after processing each page to allow the garbage collector free the memory held by the browser control - remove it from form.Controls and add a new instance.